# Haskell - Remove elements in a list of tuples that are greater than n

Tags: list, haskell

how would i remove elements in a list of tuples that are greater than n?

the list of tuples is like so: `[("abcde",1),("fghi",5),("jklm",10)]`

etc if i was to remove elements greater than 6:

```
 [("abcde",1),("fghi",5)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with filter and a lambda like so:

```
filter (\(a,b) -> b < 7 ) list
```